# Get values of KerasTensor

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

Is there a way to get the values of a Keras Tensor as a numpy array?
A normal `K.eval()` does not work and results in:

```
AttributeError: 'KerasTensor' object has no attribute 'numpy'
```

I use the eager execution.
I need this to access and check the outputs of some layers of my sequential model. Example: (`out2 = K.eval(cnn.layers[2].output)`)

Minimal example:

```
import numpy
import tensorflow.keras.models as models
import tensorflow.keras.layers as layers
from keras import backend as K

cnn = models.Sequential([
    layers.Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=3, activation='relu',
                  kernel_initializer='he_uniform', padding='same',
                  input_shape=(32,32,3))],
    name='cnn')

res = cnn(numpy.random.random((1,32,32,3)))

print(K.eval(cnn.layers[0].output))
```

Comment: You need to include code, as a tensor without context is not really evaluable.

Comment: Tensorflow v1 or v2?

Comment: Tensorflow v2.5

Comment: You have an XY problem here, asking about what you think the solution to your problem is, instead of asking about the actual problem.

Answer (score 1):

**Do not** mix `keras` with `tensorflow.keras`, i.e.

```
from keras import backend as K 
#wrong, do not import anything from keras and mix them with tensorflow
```

To get intermediate outputs from a model:

```
#for example, to get the intermediate outputs from model.layers[2]
temp_model=tf.keras.Model(model.input,model.layers[2].output)
print(temp_model(np.random.rand(1,32,32,3)).numpy())
```